# React "Use" Hook - Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.use) is not a function

Tags: react-hooks, usehooks-ts

I'm using react experimental with node 18 & trying to implement 'use' hook for a handling a promise. Getting the following error an unable to find a solution. I assume it's something related to a Webpack configuration required.

package.json

```
"react": "experimental",
"react-dom": "experimental",
```

JS File

```
import {use, useState, Suspense} from 'react'


const Component = ({url}) => {

    const fetchPromise = fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    const data = use(fetchPromise);

    return (
        <div>
            {data}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Getting the following error

```
bundle.js:3509 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.use) is not a function
    at Component (bundle.js:3509:58)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Comment: React doesn't have a `use` export, I think what you’re looking for is `useEffect`

Comment: @user16967562: No, not 'useEffect' I've seen some people importing 'use' hook from react experimental version. That's what I was trying out.

Answer (score 1):

It really make sense to pass `url` as a prop, this is how it should be done:

```js
const Component = ({ url }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(_data => setData(_data))
  }, [])

  return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

Do not use experimental versions for your packages, they may contain bugs.

**Edit:**

I created an example and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-glade-zh1w08?file=/src/App.js

```js
import { use } from "react";

const getProduct = fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products/1").then((res) =>
  res.json()
);

function App() {
  const product = use(getProduct);
  if (!product) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return <div>{product.title}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. That approach would work. But I actually was trying to do is just try out the 'use' hook in experimental version to see how I can handle async code in very few code lines. Was not planning to use it in production. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh I just checked it out, that’s kinda of nice, maybe you forgot to run `yarn install` or `npm install`

Comment: Looks like the promise has to be outside the component.

Comment: Is that codesandbox working for you ? I'm seeing a ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js' relative to '/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js'

I tried, deleting the node modules & rerunning npm i & also having the promise outside of the Component. No luck.

Comment: Yes codesandbox works, maybe try crating a new react project?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you are using Next js I think the solution is just to input "use client" at the top of your code. And "use client" was the solution.